# Redirect 2to3 output to new file

Tags: python-3.x, python-2to3

When I run `2to3.py -w my_script.py` it converts `my_script.py` to Python3 and then puts the original version `my_script.py.bak`.

I want the old file to remain as is, and the converted file to go into a new file, like `my_script.converted.py`. Is there a `2to3.py` argument that allows this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's several options for this:

- Copy the file first to a new location, then run `2to3 -w -n` which modifies the file in place (`-w`) without making a backup (`-n`)
- `2to3 -n -o desired/path/to/new/file` specifies an output directory (`-o`) and disables backup (`-n`)
- `2to3 -n -W --add-suffix=3` will put the file in the same location, but put a suffix on it (`-W --add-suffix=`) without making a backup (`n`)